# Python - Error in for loop statement (updating to salesforce)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, salesforce

I have a dataframe of two columns namely Id and datetimehelp (Holds time stamp value).

Given below is the view of the data in the dataframe (account_update_subset)

```
Id,datetimehelp
123,18/05/18 9:50
234,NaT
567,18/05/18 9:45
```

I am writing the below Python code to have this update to a Salesforce object but it throws me an error **Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}**

```
if len(account_update_subset) > 0:
    key_update_attributes_list = []
    update_attributes_list = []
    for i in range(len(account_update_subset)):
        update_attributes_data = {'Id': account_update_subset['Id'].iloc[i],
                              'datetimehelp': account_update_subset['datetimehelp'].iloc[i]}

        update_attributes_list.append(update_attributes_data)
        sf_data_cursor.bulk.Account.update(update_attributes_list)
```

Could anyone help me find where am I going wrong in this Python script. Thanks

Comment: How working if remove rows with `NaT`s ? `account_update_subset = account_update_subset.dropna(subset=['datetimehelp'])` ?

Comment: You could try-except for `KeyError` or test whether `account_update_subset` contains `'Id'` and `'datetimehelp'` before you reference them in the first line in the loop.

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the reply but 'dropna' still did not remove the NaT values from the column.

Comment: Then try `account_update_subset = account_update_subset[account_update_subset['datetimehelp'] != 'NaT']`

Comment: @RonKalian, Yes I did export the Df to a csv and find the value intact and only then process it in the loop..

Comment: @jezrael, thanks that helped filter out the NaT's but the error still holds true..

Comment: @darkhorse - Then no idea, sorry.

Comment: @jezrael  no issues, thanks for your help..

Comment: Is it what you want that you extend `update_attributes_list` with each iteration of the loop and then update the whole list, including the items already updated with the previous iteration of the loop?

Comment: @Jeronimo, yep this code works just fine if the time format is dd/mm/yy. But if I change it to dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss this error pops out..